# Geological position in not stored in variables in Angular 2. I am trying to display latitude and longitude in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

```
lat;
lng;
getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
  } else { 
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
showPosition(position) {
console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
  this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  this.lng =  position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(this.lat);
}
```

I am trying to get user's current position on load of the application. And for that I am using HTML5 geological functionality. But it is working fine in JavaScript but not in Angular 2 which follows TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

> You need two things to make that happen

1. You need to include `"dom"` in `"lib"` section of your tsconfig.json. Which essentially tells the TypeScript compiler to avail dom and bom related features like

   `"navigator","console", "window", "event", "document", etc`

   ```
   {
     "compileOnSave": false,
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "declaration": false,
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "target": "es5",
       "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types"
       ],
       "lib": [
         "es2017",
         "dom"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. You need to use Fat Arrow expression instead of anonymous function. Reason being, normal function cannot access this keyword. Inside anonymous function, this keyword refers to the function itself. Lambda expression was introduced to overcome this quirk of JavaScript.

   ```
   lat: any;
   lng: any;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.getLocation();
   }

   getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
         this.showPosition(position);
       });
     } else {
       alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
     }
   }

   showPosition(position) {
     console.log(
       "Latitude: " +
         position.coords.latitude +
         "Longitude: " +
         position.coords.longitude
     );
     this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
     this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
     console.log(this.lat);
   }
   ```